# Image not showing using the epstopdf package

Tags: epstopdf

I've been trying to get the 'epstopdf' package and have been bumping to a lot of issues. I finally get to run the file with no errors. But the image is not showing, instead there is a lot of text cramped-up.

```
    \documentclass[12pt,twoside]{mitthesis}
    \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
    \usepackage{epstopdf}
    \usepackage{color}
    \usepackage{transparent}
    \usepackage[]{algorithm2e}
    \usepackage{algorithms}
    \usepackage{subfig}
    \usepackage{hhline}
    \usepackage{amsmath} 
    \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
    \usepackage{epstopdf}
    \usepackage{color}
    \usepackage{transparent}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering
\graphicpath{{Inkscape/}}
\def\svgwidth{1\pagewidth}

  \begingroup%
  \makeatletter%
  \providecommand\color[2][]{%
    \errmessage{(Inkscape) Color is used for the text in Inkscape, but the package 'color.sty' is not loaded}%
    \renewcommand\color[2][]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\transparent[1]{%
    \errmessage{(Inkscape) Transparency is used (non-zero) for the text in Inkscape, but the package 'transparent.sty' is not loaded}%
    \renewcommand\transparent[1]{}%
  }%
  \providecommand\rotatebox[2]{#2}%
  \ifx\svgwidth\undefined%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{571.23355406bp}%
    \ifx\svgscale\undefined%
      \relax%
    \else%
      \setlength{\unitlength}{\unitlength * \real{\svgscale}}%
    \fi%
  \else%
    \setlength{\unitlength}{\svgwidth}%
  \fi%
  \global\let\svgwidth\undefined%
  \global\let\svgscale\undefined%
  \makeatother%
  \begin{picture}(1,0.52560219)%
    \put(0,0){\includegraphics[width=\unitlength]{AC_system.eps}}%
    \put(0.61248205,0.4970148){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[b]{\smash{$Overhead Line/Positive Feeder$}}}%
    \put(0.61199996,0.00436966){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[b]{\smash{$Negative Feeder$}}}%
    \put(0.61289235,0.22564519){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[b]{\smash{$Rail$}}}%
    \put(0.23435301,0.50964167){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[b]{\smash{$Power$\\$Transformer$}}}%
    \put(0.52285146,0.15575975){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[b]{\smash{$AT_1$}}}%
    \put(0.78334036,0.15562127){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[b]{\smash{$AT_2$}}}%
    \put(0.91218434,0.15562127){\color[rgb]{0,0,0}\makebox(0,0)[b]{\smash{$AT_3$}}}%
      \end{picture}%
    \endgroup%

    \caption{AC bivoltage traction system}
    \label{fig:bivoltage}
    \end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

Option 2, using the input command instead of the code. (eps files in: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/sqqq21adv2nptsw/AADQ6LMgttTrtMPbVkHA60Dba?dl=0)

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{mitthesis}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{transparent}
\usepackage[]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{algorithms}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{transparent}

 \begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \graphicpath{{Inkscape/}}
    \def\svgwidth{1\pagewidth}
    \input{Inkscape/AC_system.eps_tex}
    \caption{AC bivoltage traction system}
    \label{fig:bivoltage}
    \end{figure}
  \end{document}
```

I'm attaching a screenshot of the result. Hope you can help :)[image: Result image in the pdf file]

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) fulle minimal example please. What is in `AC_system.eps_tex`. As long as the MWE is not something the rest of us can run on our own systems, it might be difficult to help.

Comment: Hey! Thanks. A bit more info: that file is the export i get from Inkskape (it is a small electrical system) as a code to supposedly be imported in latex. I can provide a copy of it.

Comment: A link to [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: Just edited a bit the code. I guess the only thing missing is a copy of the AC_system.eps_tex ... I'm trying to figure out how to get it for you.

Comment: As Christian mentions, still is still not enough. We need something that we can copy and compile without having to add anything to it. For example it might be an idea to include the contents of `AC_syste.eps_tex` instead of the `\input` line

Comment: You are still missing some, what is the document class?

Comment: And can the `.eps` be downloaded somewhere?

Comment: Updated the document class. My .eps can be seen in:

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/sqqq21adv2nptsw/AADQ6LMgttTrtMPbVkHA60Dba?dl=0

The .eps_tex is also in that folder in case you want to use the \input command instead of the whole code.

Comment: Does it even compile without errors on your system? I had to make several edits to make it compile. You might like to look into those first.

Comment: Yes, option 2 runs and compiles without errors. It just shows up a blank page with the cramped text as shown in the attached image. I would expect it to show an image of my electric system in a blank page.

Comment: I just ran Option 1 as well and it runs in the exact same way.

Comment: I don't understand your requirement precisely, but the
figure itself is simply obtained as follows.
I don't have mitthesis.cls, so I use article.cls:
`% pdflatex`
`\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article}`
`\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}`
`\usepackage{epstopdf}`
`\begin{document}`
`\begin{figure}[htb]`
`\centering`
`\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{AC_system.eps}`
`\caption{AC bivoltage traction system}`
`\label{fig:bivoltage}`
`\end{figure}`
`\end{document}`

Comment: I see your point. But when running it like you only results in a square that has the text:

"Inkscape/AC_system-eps-converted-to.pdf"

And an error in the console that reads:

Package pdftex.def Error: File `Inkscape/AC_system-eps-converted-to.pdf' not found.

Comment: It seems that somehow the package is failing to create the pdf file from the eps. And without it it is not really adding anything.

Answer (score 1):

> It seems that the following option works well, but there are a few
>   things to consider.
>
> 1. There is a known error when using Quartz11, sometimes when Latex is calling Quartz to perform the pdf transformation it calls the old
>      version of X11 instead. Since it doesn't exist anymore it never
>      creates the pdf conversion. The solution to this is to re-install
>      Quartz11.
> 2. The epstopdf works best with the latest version of Tex. In my case just installing the latest version of the MACTEX package seemed to
>      have solved the issue.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{mitthesis}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{transparent}
 \begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \graphicpath{{Inkscape/}}
    \def\svgwidth{1\pagewidth}
    \input{Inkscape/AC_system.eps_tex}
    \caption{AC bivoltage traction system}
    \label{fig:bivoltage}
    \end{figure}
  \end{document}
```